# Get HTML element contained in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `document.getSelection()` to select some text. I would like to know what type of element the selected range contains (I specifically want to see if it is an anchor tag).

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
```

So I can get the range, but how can I know what element is in that range? Happy to use plain js or jQuery.

**EDIT:**

Here is what I came up with:

```
var updateLink = function(url) {

    var selection = document.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    if (range != 0) {
        var containerElement = range.commonAncestorContainer;
        if (containerElement.nodeType != 1) {
            containerElement = containerElement.parentNode;
            var e = $(containerElement);
            e.attr('href', url);
        }

    }

}//end
```

Comment: read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FSelection

Comment: Try using [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/), it makes working with selections *much* easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj = document.getSelection();
var parentNode = $(obj.anchorNode).parent();
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/54yg7/)

Comment: Works super well. I modified it a bit for my usage, but exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cloneContents()` method:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PPWYB/1/)

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
        selectionContents = range.cloneContents();

    alert($(selectionContents.childNodes).filter('a').length);
});
```